# Switch with multiple conditions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I have a table where I would like to add some colour to the cells based on the total

```
    Name     Total
    Alex      12
    Harry      6
```

Using the following switch statement the 'Total' cell does turn Light Green.

```
=switch(Fields!Name.value ="Alex" and Fields!Total.value >=11, "LightGreen", Fields!Name.value = "Alex" and Fields!Total.value >=8 and Fields!Total.value <=10, "Orange",  Fields!Name.value = "Alex" and Fields!Total.value <=7,"Red")
```

However I would now like to make the 'Total' field for 'Harry' to turn Red.  I have tried the following but this has not worked

```
=switch(Fields!Name.value ="Alex" and Fields!Total.value >=11, "LightGreen", Fields!Name.value = "Alex" and Fields!Total.value >=8 and Fields!Total.value <=10, "Orange",  Fields!Name.value = "Alex" and Fields!Total.value <=7,"Red")  or  switch(Fields!Name.value ="Harry" and Fields!Total.value >=11, "LightGreen", Fields!Name.value = "Harry" and Fields!Total.value >=8 and Fields!Total.value <=10, "Orange",  Fields!Name.value = "Harry" and Fields!Total.value <=7,"Red")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to answer my own question.  I used 'Or' in the second switch statement, swapping this with a comma solved the problem